# How to limit the number of friends a user can invite in a facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use this function that prompts the end user to choose multiple friends to invite:

```
 function sendRequest() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Check out this application!',
            filters: ['app_non_users'],
            title: 'Send your friends an application request',
        }
```

This works preety good, But i want to limit the number of friends the user
can invite in the popup facebook ui. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
request_ids = FB.ui({
   method: 'apprequests',
   access_token: '<?php echo $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']; ?>',
   display: 'iframe',
   max_recipients: '5',
   message: 'message', 
   data: 'data' });
```